Overlapping submenu items when hovering over the item
I'm new at creating websites and I have a navigation bar working and I added a dropdown with multiple submenus. When I hover a submenu the submenu item opens and stays open even though I hover over another submenu. Hopefully I'm explaining this correctly. I have done a lot of searching and cannot find how to prevent the submenu items from overlapping when I hover over them. Hoping someone can help. Here is the HTML code with the style for the submenu and the extra CSS I use for my working navigation bar.
You would have to hover over "Greys Corner" and then on the submenus.
I would like for the submenu items not to overlap. In other words, I would like to see the submenu item to close when I hover over the next submenu.


/*CSS: This CSS is what I use for the working part of my navigation bar.*/

body {
  background-color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #045D5D;
  /*dark teal*/
}

li {
  float: left;
  background-size: 30px;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #307D7E;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #3B9C9C;
  /*background-color: #f9f9f9;*/
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.rightNav {
  text-align: right;
}

#search {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #ffd700;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  /* Change the background color on hover */
  color: #ffd700;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

<!-- This changed the font size on the complete page -->p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 20% margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 8px;
  width: 90%;
}

.about-section {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #474e5d;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.container::after,
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.title {
  color: blue;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}

.text {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap script -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Font-Awesome script -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="/html/css/test_navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    .dropdown-menu {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #3B9C9C;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 9999;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      /*text-align: left;*/
    }
    
    .dropend .dropdown-toggle {
      color: black;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-item:hover {
      background-color: black;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu,
    .dropend:hover>.dropdown-menu {
      display: block;
      margin-top: .125em;
      margin-left: .125em;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width:992px) {
      .dropend:hover>.dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
      }
      .dropend .dropdown-toggle {
        margin-left: .5em;
      }
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>
  <!--<nav class="navbar"> -->
  <div>
    <ul>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Events</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">2024 Parade</a>
          <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">River Parade</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Greys Corner</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content dropend">
          <a href="#" style="font-size:15px;" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Health</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" aria-expanded="false">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px">Item2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px">Item3</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="dropdown-content dropend">
            <a href="#" style="font-size:15px" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Prepared</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px">Emergency</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px">Prepared</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="dropdown-content dropend">
              <a href="#" style="font-size:15px" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Ready</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px">Ready1</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px">Ready2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Store</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">Apparel1</a>
          <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">Apparel2</a>
          <!--<a href="#">Link 3</a>-->
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>




Please click [edit] then the [<>] and create a [mcve] of VALID HTML. Add any framework you use



/* --------------------- primary menu ------------------------------- */
.primary-menu li, .menu-full li  { display: inline-block; }
.primary-menu li a:link, .primary-menu li a:visited { text-transform: uppercase; display: block; padding: 15px 15px; font-size: 11.5pt; letter-spacing: 1px;  position: relative; color: var(--color);   }
.primary-menu .sbMenu { position: relative;}
.dpMenu, .dpMenuSub, .treatMenu-dp { position: absolute; top: 45px; left: 0; z-index: 1200; display:none; padding-top: 0px; box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);  }
.dpMenuSub { display: none; left: -170px; top: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100px; text-align: left !important; line-height: 22px; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #fff; column-gap: 10px;} /*------ Change made here secondary drop menu width ------- */
.subMenuDp { position: relative; }
.primary-menu-sub-wrapp  .dpMenu { top: 35px; margin-top: -10px;}
.primary-menu .dpMenu a:link, .primary-menu .dpMenu a:visited { padding: 15px 20px; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #fff;  display: block; width: 100%; color: var(--color); text-align: left;}
.primary-menu .dpMenu li { display: block;}
.primary-menu .dpMenu a:after { display: none;}
.primary-menu .dpMenu { background-color: transparent; width: 100px;  } /*------ Change made here primary drop menu width ------- */
.sbMenu:hover .dpMenu, .treatMenu-sub:hover .treatMenu-dp { display: block; animation: dpAnim 0.5s ease forwards; opacity: 0;}
/* .subMenuDp:hover .dpMenuSub  { display: block; animation: dpAnimSub 0.5s ease forwards; opacity: 0;}  */
.primary-menu-sub-wrapp  .primary-menu li a:link, .primary-menu-sub-wrapp  .primary-menu li a:visited {padding: 20px 20px; color: #fff;}
.primary-menu-sub-wrapp  .primary-menu li a:after { display: none;}
.primary-menu-sub-wrapp .primary-menu .dpMenu a:link, .primary-menu-sub-wrapp .primary-menu .dpMenu a:visited  { color: var(--color); padding: 15px 20px;}
.primary-menu-sub-wrapp  .primary-menu li a.downArrow:after { display: block; width: 10px; height: 10px;  position: absolute; top: 30px; right: 0; background-color: transparent; }
@keyframes dpAnim {   0% { opacity: 0;  top: 80px;}   100% { opacity: 1; top: 50px;} }
.primary-menu .dpMenuSub li { width: calc(100% - 10px) !important; } /*------ width change to 100% ------- */
 .dpMenu li:hover .dpMenuSub  { display: block; animation: dpAnimSub 0.5s ease forwards; opacity: 0;}  /*------ display flex to block ------- */
.primary-menu .sbMenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1; }
@keyframes dpAnimSub {    0% { opacity: 0;  left: 150px;}   100% { opacity: 1; left: 170px;} }   /*------  please change according to primary sub menu with ------- */

/* ---- for grey color i think its border color you can change to what ever ---- /*
<div class="primary-menu">
    <ul>      
        <li class="sbMenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Events</a>
            <ul class="dpMenu">
              <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">2024 Parade</a>
              <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">River Parade</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sbMenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Greys Corner</a>
    
            <ul class="dpMenu">      
          <li>
                <a href="#" >Health</a>
                <ul class="dpMenuSub">
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" aria-expanded="false">Item1</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px">Item2</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px">Item3</a></li>
                  </ul>
    
    
                </li>
    
    
             <li>
                        <a href="#" >Prepared</a>
                        <ul class="dpMenuSub">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" >Emergency</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" >Prepared</a></li>
                        </ul>
    
                </li>
    
    
                        
                    <li>
                            <a href="#" >Ready</a>
                            <ul class="dpMenuSub">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" >Ready1</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" >Ready2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
        
    
        </ul>
        </li>
         
        <li class="sbMenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Store</a>
            <ul class="dpMenu">
                <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">Apparel1</a>
                <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">Apparel2</a>
                <!--<a href="#">Link 3</a>-->
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>





.primary-menu li, .menu-full li  { display: inline-block; }
.primary-menu li a:link, .primary-menu li a:visited { text-transform: uppercase; display: block; padding: 25px 15px; font-size: 11.5pt; letter-spacing: 1px;  position: relative; color: var(--color);   }
.primary-menu .sbMenu { position: relative;}
.dpMenu, .dpMenuSub, .treatMenu-dp { position: absolute; top: 45px; left: 0; z-index: 1200; display:none; padding-top: 0px; box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);  }
.dpMenuSub { display: none; left: -260px; top: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 600px; text-align: left !important; line-height: 22px; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #fff; column-gap: 10px;}
.subMenuDp { position: relative; }
.primary-menu-sub-wrapp  .dpMenu { top: 35px; margin-top: -10px;}
.primary-menu .dpMenu a:link, .primary-menu .dpMenu a:visited { padding: 15px 20px; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #fff;  display: block; width: 100%; color: var(--color); text-align: left;}
.primary-menu .dpMenu li { display: block;}
.primary-menu .dpMenu a:after { display: none;}
.primary-menu .dpMenu { background-color: transparent; width: 260px;  }
.sbMenu:hover .dpMenu, .treatMenu-sub:hover .treatMenu-dp { display: block; animation: dpAnim 0.5s ease forwards; opacity: 0;}
/* .subMenuDp:hover .dpMenuSub  { display: block; animation: dpAnimSub 0.5s ease forwards; opacity: 0;}  */
.primary-menu-sub-wrapp  .primary-menu li a:link, .primary-menu-sub-wrapp  .primary-menu li a:visited {padding: 20px 20px; color: #fff;}
.primary-menu-sub-wrapp  .primary-menu li a:after { display: none;}
.primary-menu-sub-wrapp .primary-menu .dpMenu a:link, .primary-menu-sub-wrapp .primary-menu .dpMenu a:visited  { color: var(--color); padding: 15px 20px;}
.primary-menu-sub-wrapp  .primary-menu li a.downArrow:after { display: block; width: 10px; height: 10px;  position: absolute; top: 30px; right: 0; background-color: transparent; }
@keyframes dpAnim {   0% { opacity: 0;  top: 80px;}   100% { opacity: 1; top: 50px;} }
.primary-menu .dpMenuSub li { width: calc(50% - 10px) !important; }
 .dpMenu li:hover .dpMenuSub  { display: flex; animation: dpAnimSub 0.5s ease forwards; opacity: 0;} 
.primary-menu .sbMenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1; }
@keyframes dpAnimSub {    0% { opacity: 0;  left: 250px;}   100% { opacity: 1; left: 260px;} } 
<div class="primary-menu">
    <ul>      
        <li class="sbMenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Events</a>
            <ul class="dpMenu">
              <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">2024 Parade</a>
              <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">River Parade</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sbMenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Greys Corner</a>
    
            <ul class="dpMenu">      
          <li>
                <a href="#" >Health</a>
                <ul class="dpMenuSub">
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" aria-expanded="false">Item1</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px">Item2</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px">Item3</a></li>
                  </ul>
    
    
                </li>
    
    
             <li>
                        <a href="#" >Prepared</a>
                        <ul class="dpMenuSub">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" >Emergency</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" >Prepared</a></li>
                        </ul>
    
                </li>
    
    
                        
                    <li>
                            <a href="#" >Ready</a>
                            <ul class="dpMenuSub">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" >Ready1</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-size:15px" >Ready2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
        
    
        </ul>
        </li>
         
        <li class="sbMenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Store</a>
            <ul class="dpMenu">
                <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">Apparel1</a>
                <a href="#" style="font-size:15px">Apparel2</a>
                <!--<a href="#">Link 3</a>-->
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>


</div>




Please comment on what you did. Code only answers do not explain the solution

Sorry .... I removed all js and changed class name and re-write whole code... code is not the same as the question. please copy entire css and html. hopes it helps.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I tried the snippet and it looks good. I will try it in my code and come back with the results.

I used the code provided by Gadhafi, I'm wondering how can I modify the size of the class=sbMenu and class=dpmenuSub. I tried a few things and was not successul. I would like to make them slighty smaller.

Here is my edited comment:  I used the code provided by Gadhafi, I'm wondering how can I modify the size of the class=sbMenu and class=dpMenuSub. I tried a few things and was not successul. I would like to make them slighty smaller or shall I say not as wide. I don't want to see a grey area between the dbMenuSub.

you can change "dpMenuSub" width by cheaging width of the same class and  .dpMenu li:hover .dpMenuSub { display:flex } to display:block;  .primary-menu .dpMenuSub li { width: calc(100% - 10px) !important; } ...

Please refer edited version i commented all the changes made

I will give it a try.
